# Find username with userID and without access_token

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Are there any ways, to find an user with his userid and without an access token?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this endpoint with `client_id`, the documentation on instagram says `access_token` is required, but it works with just `client_id`

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/?client_id={CLIENT_ID}
```